# Why same ssh command get different results on different platform:debian and win7's cygwin?

Tags: shell, ssh, cygwin, tunnel

There are dual os on my computer.
The ssh same command get different results on different platform.
In my debian8 os :

```
ssh -CNfg -L 22:127.0.0.1:10020 -p 28120 root@my_vps_ip
```

No error info output.
Now reboot my pc and enter into my win7 os.
In my win7 platform:cygwin and openssh plugin in it,sshd was set properly and make sshd run.

```
ssh -CNfg -L 22:127.0.0.1:10020 -p 28120 root@my_vps_ip
root@my_vps_ip's password:
bind: Address already in use
channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 22
Could not request local forwarding.
```

Why same ssh command get different results on different platform:debian and win7's cygwin?

Two more discovery.
1.To start cygwin as administrator,the same error info for the command:

```
ssh -CNfg -L 22:127.0.0.1:10020 -p 28120 root@my_vps_ip
```

2.i change port number 22 into 2222 ,no error info output now.

```
ssh -CNfg -L 2222:127.0.0.1:10020 -p 28120 root@my_vps_ip
```

Why no error info when to change port 22 into port 2222 ?

Comment: Generally, your $HOME dir in linux will be a different set than the $HOME dir under cywin AND all of the cfg files used by `ssh` will be different. (unless you have deliberately copied file sets between the two systems). Also the `ssh -v` may be different (and the default values in the system level `ssh` config files. Good luck.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You are trying to bind local port 22 and I guess you don't have privileges to do so under `cygwin`, unless you start it as some kind of administrator.